# Сортировка массива объектов по string полю

Tags: c++, строки, vector, qsort

Есть такой класс администратора

```
class Admin
{
public:
    Admin() {}
    Admin(string log, string pass): login(log), password(pass) {}
    ~Admin() {}
    string get_login() { return login; }
    string get_password() { return password; }
    static int a_Login(string Login, string Password);
    static void a_Menu();
    static void a_print();
    static void a_delete();
    static void a_add();
    static void a_edit();
    static void a_sort(int ascend=1);
    static void load_data();
    static void read_admins();
    static void write_admins();
    static string current_admin;
protected:
    static int ascend_comp_login(const void* a, const void* b);
    static int descend_comp_login(const void* a, const void* b);
    string login, password;
};
```

И такие компараторы и сам метод, который вызывает qsort

```
int Admin::ascend_comp_login(const void* a,const void* b)
{
    string l = ((Admin*)a)->get_login();
    string r = ((Admin*)b)->get_login();
    return l.compare(r);
}
int Admin::descend_comp_login(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    string l = ((Admin*)a)->get_login();
    string r = ((Admin*)b)->get_login();
    return r.compare(l);
}
void Admin::a_sort(int ascend)
{
    if (ascend) qsort(&admins, admins.size(), sizeof(Admin), ascend_comp_login);
    else qsort(&admins, admins.size(), sizeof(Admin), descend_comp_login);
    Admin::a_print();
}
```

admins это вектор типа `vector<Admin>`

После таких преобразований сначала в войд, а потом обратно в админ, видимо, теряется инфа т.к. геттер возвращает либо рандомный мусор, либо пустую строку

Как это исправить, что бы по итогу использовать `qsort` ?

Comment: вы передаете в функцию указатель на сам вектор, а не на данные вектора. Используйте vector::data (https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) `qsort(admins.data()...` также рассмотрите вариант использования алгоритмов сортировки из <algorithm> на итераторах

Comment: использовать qsort для сортировки С_строк, понятно. Но зачем пытаться его использовать при работе со стандартными контейнерами? Чтобы    выглядело сложнее код?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan а как тогда лучше сортировать?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan вы про sort хотели написать? Не знаю, просто раньше использвал qsort :/

Comment: кстати, еще у вас некорректно вычисляется размер данных, вы передаете количество элементов вектора, а надо количество байт admins.size() * sizeof(Admin)

Comment: @goldstar_labs наоборот исключение кидает, если так пишу. А с просто сайз нормально сортирует

Comment: Не знаю, как ответить на вопрос, где Админ имеет один логин и один пороль, и работает только со статическими данными, которых не имеет...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan данные хранятся в векторе, в вопросе написано. У каждого объекта есть логин и пароль. Статические поля работают с самим вектором. Ответ уже дан, всё сработало

Comment: Я просто намекал на  степень полезности кода, остальное дело хозяйское...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Кстати, что делать, есть ответ дан, но он опубликован в комментариях? Удалить вопрос?

Comment: да, с размером я был неправ, надо передавать количество элементов

Comment: @dhvcc, нет, вы меня неправильно понимаете, я пытаюсь вам подсказать, что нужно выбрать другую путь,  другой подход . Если вам это не нужно,  дело ваше. Я не говорил, что вопрос бесполезен, я говорю, что   считаю ваш класс бесполезным.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вы передаете в функцию указатель на сам вектор, а не на данные вектора. Используйте [vector::data](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data)

```
qsort(admins.data(), ...);
```

также рассмотрите вариант использования алгоритмов сортировки из `<algorithm>` на итераторах, [std::sort](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)